# How do I prevent adding an object in multiple vectors?

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns, vector, data-structures

There are some objects that are `Drawable` and some that are `Movable`.
All movable objects are dawable.
I store all the drawable objects in a vector called `drawables` and movable objects in a vector called `movables`. 
I also have vectors `ships` and `bullets` which contain objects of type `Ship` and `Bullet` respectively.
`Ship` and `Bullet` both are `Movable`

Here's the structure of the classes:

```
class Drawable {
public:
    void draw();
};

class Movable : public Drawable {
public:
    void move();
}

class Ship : public Movable {
public:
    Ship();
}

class Bullet : public Movable {
public:
    Bullet();
}
```

The vectors are declared as follows:

```
std::vector<Drawable*> drawables;
std::vector<Movable*> movables;
std::vector<Ship*> ships;
std::vector<Bullet*> bullets;
```

The thing is, that each time I create a Ship I have to add it in all the vectors i.e.

```
drawables.push_back(ship);
movables.push_back(ship);
ships.push_back(ship);
```

I have created separate `drawables` and `movables` vectors since I have a `draw()` function which calls the `draw()` method of all objects in the `drawables` vector. Similarly, I have a `move()` function which calls the `move()` method of all objects in the `movables` vector.

My question is, how do I change the structure to prevent adding the same thing in different vectors. I also need to remove objects from all the vectors once it's purpose is done.
For example, once the bullet hits someone or moves out of the screen, then I'll have to remove it from the vectors `drawables`, `movables` and `bullets` after searching it in all three vectors.
It seems like I'm not using the correct approach for storing these objects. Please suggest an alternative.

This seems more like a software engineering question than a coding question. Please migrate the question to other forum if necessary.

Comment: Can you show more code - include your declarations?

Comment: @Galik added the declarations of vectors and classes

Comment: Look up entity component system, it's a de facto standard structure for games.

Comment: Your question contains a contradiction. In the text, you state "All drawable objects are movable", yet the code indicates the converse: `Movable` derives from `Drawable`, meaning that all movable objects are drawable.

Comment: As for the actual question: why do you have the different vectors in the first place? If your reason was good, then maybe its OK to have the same things in them. (Since you are storing pointers instead of copies, the overhead is not huge.) There are ways to make the vectors easier to maintain, but first you need to decide what you want.

Comment: @JaMiT i edited that sentence.
I have different vectors so that I can call `move()` function on objects of `Movable` and `draw()` on all objects of `Drawable` in seperate functions. Also, if an object is out of bounds, then I can perform appropriate operation on it based on whether it is in `bullets` or `ships` vector. Thank you for your comment. Would be cool if you suggest an alternative to represent these things. It's not a really big project and I'm doing it just to learn so I'll make any changes necessary to make it better. Thanks, again!

Comment: Note that we don't know how you manage the lifetime of your objects. A valid answer to the question as written might not work in your specific situation. So use some judgement when evaluating answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a reasonably modern compiler, this is exactly why [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) exists.

The problem is that you have no idea which vector owns the object, so you don't know which one to delete. `shared_ptr` takes are of this for you: it manages the lifetime of the object, and will delete it once the last reference to the object is destroyed.

To create a new `Ship`, you could do something like this:

```
auto ship = std::make_shared<Ship>();

drawables.push_back(ship);
movables.push_back(ship);
ships.push_back(ship);
```

At this point `ship` has 4 references (one for each vector, and the `ship` variable itself). It will automatically be deleted once it has been removed from all three vectors and the local variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Or possibly use `weak_ptr` in the vectors, if they are not required to keep the object alive. You could do the deletions from the vectors when iterating over them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to maintain a container of (pointers to) all objects of a certain type, you may want to take a RAII approach. Have the object's constructor add to the container, and the destructor remove from it. You'd also want to make sure nothing else modifies the container, so it should be a private (static) member of your class, with a public method to provide read-only access.

Even better, move this logic into its own class, so it can be re-used. This would also allow your existing containers to remain focused on what they currently do. They would just need a new data member of the helper class type.

To ease removals, I would consider using a `list` instead of a `vector`. Also, it might be worth using `reference_wrapper` instead of pointers. A pointer can have a null value. While you can document that the container will have no null pointers, a `reference_wrapper` conveys this with no additional documentation.

To get you started, here is the start of a helper class template you could use.

```
template <class T>
class All {
        using ListType = std::list< std::reference_wrapper<T> >;

    private:
        static ListType the_list;
        // A list's iterators are rarely invalidated. For a vector, you would
        // not store an iterator but instead search when removing from the_list.
        typename ListType::iterator list_it;

    public:

        // Read-only access to the list.
        static const ListType & list() { return the_list; }

        // Construction
        ListAll() : list_it(the_list.end()) {}  // If this constructor is needed
        explicit ListAll(T & data) : list_it(the_list.insert(the_list.end(), data)) {}

        // Destruction
        ~ListAll() { if ( list_it != the_list.end() ) the_list.erase(list_it); }

        // Rule of 5
        // You should also define or delete the copy constructor, move constructor,
        // copy assignment, and move assignment.

        // If you need the default constructor, then you probably want a method like:
        //void set(T & data);
};
template <class T>
typename All<T>::ListType All<T>::the_list{};
```

Names are often tough to come by. I named this template based on getting something to iterate over, for example: `All<Movable>::list()`.